# Fetching a child without fetching parent in Firebase 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to fetch a child of an object without the entire parent in Firebase 3?

For example, say I had the following structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      "username": "name",
      "phone": "7777777777",
      "email": "john@doe.com",
      "user_settings": {
        "setting": true
      },
      "public_profile": {
        "basic_info": {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "avatar": "url",
          "customer_rating": 5
        },
        "reviewsReceived": [3,5,2,8,1],
        "reviewsWritten": [9,6,4],
      }
    }
  }
```

Would it be possible for me to access `basic_info` without having to load the entire `$uid` object?

Comment: Did you try `var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/users/$uid/public_profile');` ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What language do you use? And can you share a snippet of the code you already tried?